# Put an X in the corner of a div without the text going under

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an "X" in the top-right corner of a div, but any text that collides with it will not wrap because I am using absolute positioning on the X.

```
<div class="article-listing" ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="article in filtered = (wikiArticles | filter:search)">
  <span class="article-title">{{article.title}}</span><a ng-click="articles.removeArticle($index)" class="delete-article" title="Remove article">&#10006;</a>
  <div class"article-extract">{{article.extract}}</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.article-listing {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA;
}

span.article-title {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.article-extract {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.delete-article {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #EEE;
  color: #888;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

How can I get it so if the text in the title or extract hits the X, it will wrap?

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning. Put the 'X' into a container (a div or a span) and position it relative, using `float` or `align`.

Comment: Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/6yN8j/).

Comment: @arkascha I guess position relative does work after all. Thanks to mdesdev too!

Comment: I'll try something else ;)

Comment: @mdesdev Thanks, I got it working now. Can you post an answer with your fiddle so I can accept your answer and close this question?

Comment: Ok I've posted the answer ;)

Comment: Yup. "float" was exactly designed for positioning images top right or left the the text flowing around them. Note that if you move the close box before the article title in the document flow, you don't need to float the title left. The `float` will still position the close box to the right. You don't need to keep that old `position: relative;`, either.  [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yN8j/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.article-listing {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 500px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.article-title {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #666;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 94%;
}

.article-extract {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.delete-article {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #eee;
  color: #888;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Matt Gibson's JSFiddle without title `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/6yN8j/6/